# Making background color of xul panel to transparent

Tags: popup, panel, xul, background-color, transparent

Basically I have created a popup using xul panel. Then I have a child (vbox) inside that panel.
So i want to make the background color of panel to be transparent. But when i did that using background-color: transparent , It makes the child vbox as well transparent so that it is invisible.

Is there anyway only to make the transparent for panel popup, but not to it's children.

Answer (score 2):

I found this as a test case for a [resolved bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436003) on an earlier version of FireFox. Set the style of the panel to:

```
background:transparent;
border:none;
-moz-appearance:none !important;
```

The child elements will not be transparent but the background of the panel will be.